# Map not returning array as expected from axios

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an axios post call to a graphQL mutation. In response, I need to create and array but I am getting so many `undefined` values.

My code:

```
const func = async (vars, update_vars) => {
  await axiosFunction({ query: create_fields, variables: vars }).then(
    (response) => {
      if (update_vars != undefined) {
        const yo = update_vars.att.map((att) => {
          if (
            att.label === response.data.label
          )
            return response.data.id;
        });
        console.log(yo);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

`update_vars` format:

```
[
  { label: 'val 1' },
  { label: 'val 2' },
  { label: 'val 3' },
  { label: 'val 4' }
]
```

`response.data` format

```
{
  id: '112',
  other_id: '352009093',
  label: 'val 1'
}
{
  id: '113',
  other_id: '3520012',
  label: 'val 2'
}
{
  id: '152',
  other_id: '234578',
  label: 'val 13'
}
```

I need `yo` to return `['112', '113']`

Comment: Is `update_vars` an array of arrays of objects? Please edit the input to make it valid JavaScript.

Comment: @Unmitigated `update_vars` is an array of objects. There is no comma because its a different value that comes the function

Comment: Why are there two arrays there then?

Comment: What **exactly** is the format of `update_vars`? Does it actually have an `att` property (ie `update_vars.att` in your code)?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Set` of all the label properties in the objects in `update_vars`, then `filter` the response based on them. Finally, `Array#map` can be used to extract the ids of the matching elements.

```js
let update_vars=[{label:"val 1"},{label:"val 2"},{label:"val 3"},{label:"val 4"}],response={data:[{id:"112",other_id:"352009093",label:"val 1"},{id:"113",other_id:"3520012",label:"val 2"},{id:"152",other_id:"234578",label:"val 13"}]};
const labels = new Set(update_vars.map(o => o.label));
const res = response.data.filter(({label}) => labels.has(label)).map(o => o.id);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, the solution should be something like this, obviously it can be improved.

```js
const update_var = [[
  { label: 'val 1' },
  { label: 'val 2' },
  { label: 'val 3' },
  { label: 'val 4' }
],
[
  { label: 'val 5' },
  { label: 'val 6' },
  { label: 'val 7' }
]];

var data = [{
  id: '112',
  other_id: '352009093',
  label: 'val 1'
},
{
  id: '113',
  other_id: '3520012',
  label: 'val 2'
},
{
  id: '152',
  other_id: '234578',
  label: 'val 13'
}]

const arrayFlat = update_var.flat()
const yo = []


arrayFlat.forEach(el => {
  const tmp = data.filter(e => el.label === e.label);
  if (tmp.length) {
    yo.push(tmp[0].id)
  }
});

console.log(yo)
```

The code defines an array of arrays called update_var which contains two rows of objects, each with four label keys and their corresponding string values.

Then data array is defined, which contains objects with an id, other_id, and label keys with their corresponding string values.

A new array is created by using the flat() method on the update_var array, which flattens the nested arrays into a single array.

An empty array called yo is declared.

The code then iterates through each element of the flattened arrayFlat using forEach() loop and inside the loop it filters the data array by matching the label key of each object with the label key of the current element in arrayFlat.

If there is a match, it pushes the value of the id key of the first element of the filtered array to the yo array.

Finally, the yo array is logged to the console.

This code essentially filters an array of objects (data) based on a list of labels from a nested array (update_var). Then it outputs the corresponding id values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#filter`, `Array#map` and `Array#includes` methods as follows:

```js
const 
      update_vars = [
        { label: 'val 1' },
        { label: 'val 2' },
        { label: 'val 3' },
        { label: 'val 4' }
      ],
      
      response = {
        data: [
          {
            id: '112',
            other_id: '352009093',
            label: 'val 1'
          },
          {
            id: '113',
            other_id: '3520012',
            label: 'val 2'
          },
          {
            id: '152',
            other_id: '234578',
            label: 'val 13'
          }
        ]
      },
      
      uv_labels = update_vars.map(v => v.label),
      
      output = response.data
                .filter(({label}) => uv_labels.includes(label))
                .map(({id}) => id);
                
console.log( output );
```